# Spring Data JPA intelligence not working in Intellij for OneToMany relation

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I have setup new spring boot project with Spring Data JPA and would like to use auto-completion feature to find all records by nested property.

[intellij hint for repository method is missing nested properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9UYd.png)

I want to retrieve Customers that have matching zipCodes. Declared entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;
}


@Entity
@Getter
public class Address {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String streetName;
    private String zipCode;

}
```

It should work out of the box like in article here: https://evonsdesigns.medium.com/spring-jpa-one-to-many-query-examples-281078bc457b

but it does not work. I tried it with following pom config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.7</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Tried on IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: I really don't understand your question.  If you want to retrieve data from database you must request your database. there are several ways to do that. You can use an interface that inherits CrudRepository or JpaRepository. While writing the signature of your repository methode (like findByZipCode) IntelliJ will help you with it's autocompletion.

Comment: Have you checked attached screenshot? IntelliJ is not helping while writing method that is using property of nested entity. I have created issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284683

Comment: Did you try to solve it in SQL before ? Like `SELECT c.id FROM customers c WHERE c.address_id IN (SELECT a.id FROM addresses a WHERE a.zipCode = '12345')` searches (1) first for addresses which share the given zipCode, then (2) for all customers that belong to those addresses.